# Spool out result using solidity

Tags: solidity, remix, cpp-ethereum

Does Solidity have any keyword to spool out results into an external file like .txt or .csv or .dat?

Answer (score 2):

Solidity is compiled to bytecode, which is executed in the EVM. The EVM - being a virtual machine - doesn't have direct access to the host machine it's being run on, so what you're asking for isn't possible.

Your best bet would be to use either events/logging, or use the output of the transactions/calls that you use to interact with the contract.